# Cambiar estado al pulsar sobre el botón

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy tratando de hacer el cambio de un estado de una variable cuando se entre en la pagina requerida para ello se pulsa sobre el botón *(mas detalles)* , ya que ese mismo botón me llevaría a otra pantalla.

Pero la idea es que como hay dos usuarios  cuando un usuario pulse sobre ese botón automáticamente cambie el estado de pendiente a procesado y así el otro usuario vea que se esta procesando esa consulta.

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente pero me da error:

```
  <!-- proceso para editar-->
  <?php 
    if($campo['status'] != "Procesando")
    {
    $sql2=$DB_con->prepare("UPDATE ordenes_de_pagos SET status=:Procesando 
     WHERE id_ordenes_de_pagos=:id_ordenes_de_pagos");
    $sql2->bindParam(':status',$_GET['status']);
    $sql2->bindParam(':id_ordenes_de_pagos',$_GET['id_ordenes_de_pagos']);
    $sql2->execute();
    }
    ?>
    <!-- fin proceso para editar-->
```

El error es el siguiente:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'
>   in C:**

Comment: `:Procesando` en lugar de `:status` en el `bindParam`

Comment: lo puse asi pero no me actualiza el estado: $sql2->bindParam(':Procesando',$_GET['status']);

Comment: no, mas bien se quitaron los errores pero no actualiza y los valores llegan bien

Comment: Verificar si los valores por $_GET llegan correctamente o simplemente no hay valores en la tabla con los parámetros enviados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quiero señalar algunas cosas:

1. Para un código más claro y depurable, siempre es mejor guardar los datos en variables y cuando el código no funcione, hacer `echo` de tus variables para ver que pasa.
2. Para pasar los valores, usa **[`bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)**. También puedes usar [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php), pero ten en cuenta que `bindParam` **trabaja con variables..., no con valores pasados directamente**, justamente lo que te decía en el punto **1**.
3. Verifica lo que ocurre con el `$stmt` cuando ejecutes la consulta. En el caso de `UPDATE`, como en el de `INSERT` te puedes valer de [`rowCount`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php) para saber cuántas filas fueron afectadas por la consulta.
4. Es más recomendable obtener los datos por `_$POST` en vez de `_$GET`

He aquí un ejemplo:

---

<kbd>[**VER DEMO**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wm3n-v86m)</kbd>

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user_name, $pass_word);

// Es mejor con variables
$titulo="Un hombre para la  eternidad";
$id=1;
$sql = "UPDATE books SET title=:title WHERE id=:id;";   
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindValue(":title",$titulo);
$stmt->bindValue(":id",$id);


    if ($stmt ->execute())
    {
        echo "Se actualizaron ".$stmt->rowCount()." registros";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Los registros no se  actualizaron";
    }

$pdo = null;


?>
```

**resultado**

```
Se actualizaron 1 registros
```

Comment: gracias amigo, oye necesitaba comentarte algo

Comment: @De nada.  Dime que era lo que necesitabas comentarme.

Comment: oye la otra vez vi un post que hacías referencias a los Toasts, pero me quedo una duda y por eso necesitaba una orientación tuya pero no se si por aquí se podía seguir explicando.

Comment: @yoclens Sería mejor que lo plantearas como otra pregunta, porque es la forma en que funciona SO, pero sobre todo porque podrías tener varios puntos de vista desde varias posibles respuestas de usuarios diferentes. Pero antes verifica que no exista ya una pregunta igual o parecida a la tuya con una solución válida. O si la pregunta que refieres es tuya y es sobre el mismo problema, puedes plantear la duda en comentario a mi respuesta en ella.